# How to JOIN tables without generating null for column id

Tags: sql, postgresql, supabase

I'm using Supabase and when a user calls endpoint /crypto_signals I want to do a SQL query first where I join notification table columns to **crypto_signals** based on crypto_signals id to **notifications** coin_id

**crypto_signals table**

```
id coin
1  BTC
2  ETH
3  SOL
```

**notifications table**

```
id id_coin user_id
1  1       1
2  3       2
```

**Expected response when user 1 make request to /crypto_signal**

```
id coin coin_id id_notification
1  BTC  1        1
2  ETH  null     null
3  SOL  null     null
```

**Current code so far**

```
select *
from crypto_signals
left join notifications
on crypto_signals.id = notifications.coin_id
```

Output

```
id      coin  coin_id  user_id
3       ETH   null     null
4       BTC   1       1
null    Sol   null        null
```

my crypto_signal id is lost and instead using the notifications id

EDIT SOLVED

```
select crypto_signals.*, 
notifications.id as notification_id,
notifications.coin_id
from crypto_signals
left join notifications
on crypto_signals.id = notifications.coin_id
```

Comment: Don't use `select *`. List the columns out explicitly. You're getting to `id` columns because they exist in both tables. The nulls come from using the left outer join.

Comment: Actually I got a lot more columns just didn't write it. Can I do sth like Select * from crypto_signals and while writing out the columns for notifications?

Comment: Some platforms let you do `select crypto_signals.*, notifications.id, ...` Not sure whether yours will.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick!